# Arc length and radius of a helix

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I have a cylinder of diameter $7.5\operatorname{cm}$, I want to make a helix with angle $19^o$ from horizontal plane.

What will be the profile of the helix on the helix plane? Will it be circular and if yes, then what will be its radius?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A circular helix has the following parametric representation
$$
x=r\cos t,\; y=r\sin t,\; z=ct
$$
**Our goal is to figure out $r,c$**.

> r

As the helix lies on the cylinder, they both have the same radius, therefore $r={7.5\over2}$cm.

> c

Suppose $\cdot$ represents differentiation with respect to $t$. The tangent  vector to the helix is given by
$$
(\dot x,\dot y,\dot z)=(-r\sin t,r\cos t,c)
$$
If angle between the tangent and  $z$-axis is $90^\circ-19^\circ=71^\circ$, we have
$$\begin{align}
&(\dot x,\dot y,\dot z)\cdot(0,0,1)=|(\dot x,\dot y,\dot z)|\cdot|(0,0,1)|\cos71^\circ\\
\implies&\dot z=\sqrt{\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2}\cos71^\circ\\
\implies& c=\sqrt{r^2+c^2}\cos71^\circ\\
\implies& c=r\cot71^\circ\approx1.29\text{cm}
\end{align}$$